# Failed to parse file while assigning a shape to background

Tags: android, xml, android-background

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <gradient>
      <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:shape="rectangle">
             <gradient android:type="linear"
                       android:centerX="35%" 
                       android:startColor="#FF4D0000" 
                       android:centerColor="#FF4D0000" 
                       android:endColor="#FFe5f011" 
                       android:angle="225"/>
       </shape>

    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:shape="rectangle" >
             <gradient android:type="radial"
                       android:centerX="50%" 
                       android:centerY="50%" 
                       android:startColor="#FF4D0000" 
                       android:centerColor="#FF4D0000" 
                       android:endColor="#FFe5f011" 
                       android:gradientRadius="35"/>
    </shape>
    </gradient>
```

And here is the shape that I have formed called gradient and the way I assigned it, is:

```
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
```

Comment: please help me.. i am new to android development and i like to learn if someone helps me:)

Comment: what is file name in which you put above code

Comment: @reporter Where did that extra code come from?

Comment: @MikeM. I improved the formating style from OP source code (removing spaces, etc.)

Comment: i am sorry i am new to stackoverflow.com

Comment: @reporter I don't see the linear gradient rectangle in the original post.

Comment: @reporter I try the solution given by you but the compiler produce another error

Comment: @MikeM. According the version control I didn't add any extra code.

Comment: @MikeM so there is no solution?

Comment: @reporter Whoa, that's really strange. It must be my mobile browser. Carry on.

Comment: the drawable can't have gradient as parent tag with child as shape

Comment: @BSKANIA what should be the parent tag then?

Comment: you should have two different drawable with shape tag with the child as gradient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one android xml file of type shape. give name as myshape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<gradient
    android:centerColor="#FF4D0000"
    android:centerX="50%"
    android:centerY="50%"
    android:endColor="#FFe5f011"
    android:gradientRadius="35"
    android:startColor="#FF4D0000"
    android:type="radial" />

</shape>
```

Now assign this file to the any layout with "@drawable/myshape"

I hope this will clear your doubts. 
Bskania.